# How to use Gaussian random numbers as input to a low pass filter

Tags: matlab, random, filter, numbers

I need to generate a Gaussian random numbers with zero mean and variance 2. Then use it as input to a low pass filter with cutt-off frequency of 1000Hz.

I have generated the random number as:

`k = randn(1000,1) * sqrt(2);`

But I do not know how to proceed to use a low pass filter to filter it.

And, how can I calculate the autocorrelation and power spectrum at input and output of the filter?

Comment: It sounds like you really have two separate question topics here, "how do I create a filter?", and "how do I calculate autocorrelation?". So they should be posted as separate SO questions.

Comment: Why `+1` after `randn`? That'll give you mean 1, not 0

Comment: oh sorry..ya..should be k = randn(1000,1) * sqrt(2) + 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you have the transfer function of low pass filter then convolute the input signal with filter transfer function. You can do it by using filter command.

For calculation the PSD use following code:

```
out = fft(input) ;
psd = abs(out(1:(length(out) / 2) +1)./ length(out)) ;
```

you can calculate the PSD of output of filter in same way. For calculating the auto-correlation use the xcorr command in matlab.

Low pass filter design information can be found here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9519/low-pass-filtering-using-matlab-passing-frequency-in-hz